# docker-compose-simple.yaml file giving error while composing it for running Chaincode in docker devmode

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I have Fabric v1.1 running on my Ubuntu and Below are the details of the error message which I got after running docker-compose-simple.yaml file from Fabric-Samples/Chaincode-docker-devmode path.

orderer | 2018-06-30 12:17:02.810 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 167 Adding to config map: [Value] /Channel/Consortium orderer | 2018-06-30 12:17:02.911 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 168 [channel: myc] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.20.0.5:52566 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group] /Channel/Application at version 0, but got version 1 –

orderer | 2018-06-30 12:17:03.129 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 16a Error reading from 172.20.0.5:52564: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled orderer | 2018-06-30 12:17:03.129 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 16b Closing Deliver stream

Comment: please share docker-compose.yml

Comment: Seems like this issue is still Unresolved in Jira. 
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-8591
Thanks for your comment. BTW can you please let me know what can be checked into docker-composer file?